# "Undefined is not an object on 'this2.props.options[key]'" when using key-value pair to populate Picker in react Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, key-value, picker

I am trying to populate a picker with a set of data from a key-value pair.

```js
    const options = {
      inch: 0.0254,
      foot: 0.3048,
      yard: 0.9144,
      mile: 1609.34
    };
return (
      <View>
        <Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          selectedValue={this.state.fromUnit}
          onValueChange={(unit, value) => this.setState({ fromUnit: value })}
        >
          {Object.keys(options).map(key => {
            return (
              <Picker.Item
                label={this.props.options[key]}
                value={key}
                key={key}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Picker>
```

Upon running my code, I get the following:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.options[key]')
```

I have tried adding options[] to state, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Not sure what is going on here, it looks pretty straight forward to me. It seems that it's getting caught up on the 'key' part of the mapping but I am unsure why. any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Isn't it `props.options` instead of `this.props.options` ? Or even more interesting, don't you want to use values from that `options` variable as label Item? If so, there should be `label={options[key]}`

Comment: @DominikMatis I tried that and without ```this``` it can't even find props. ```Can't find variable: props```. Removing ```this.props``` and leaving it as ```label={options[key]}``` results in expo crashing on build. Not sure what's happening here

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Want label to be inch, foot etc and values to be their values such as 0.0254, etc ?

Comment: @DominikMatis that's correct. Maybe I'm going about this incorrectly, I'm unsure

Comment: So in Picker.Item set `label` to be `key`, in `value` set `options[key]` and `key` let as `key` that should work

Comment: That did the trick @DominikMatis. thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
    const options = [
      {name: inch,  value: 0.0254},
      {name: foot, value: 0.3048},
      {name: yard, value: 0.9144},
      {name: mile, value: 1609.34}
    ];

         {options.map((options, key) => {
            return (
              <Picker.Item
                label={options.name}
                value={options.value}
                key={key}
              />
            );
          })}
```